Range.Replace suddenly replacing beyond range
Simple sub used to clear content from cells formatted in orange within a given range.  It previously worked as expected, but it is now clearing cells with the matching formatting across the entire sheet instead of just within the defined range.
I've tried changing from ActiveSheet.Range(r.Address).Replace "", "", searchformat:=True to r.Replace "", "", searchformat:=True but that yields same behavior.
Code:
Sub ClearOrangeCellsRng(r As Range)
'by range
  Application.FindFormat.Clear
  Application.FindFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 40
  ActiveSheet.Range(r.Address).Replace "", "", searchformat:=True
  Application.FindFormat.Clear
End Sub

For what its worth, the sub is being called from:
Sub BlockTemplate(n As Integer)

Dim strBlock As String
Dim nmTempl As String
Dim tblBuild, templData As ListObject
Dim BuildSht, templSht As Worksheet
Dim nTemplRows As Integer


Set BuildSht = ActiveSheet
Set templSht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("tblTemplates")

BuildSht.Unprotect

strBlock = "Build" & n & "Templ"
nmTempl = BuildSht.Range(strBlock).Value


Set tblBuild = BuildSht.ListObjects("BuildTbl" & n)
Set templData = templSht.ListObjects("tblTemplates")
 
With templData
    .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    .Range.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=nmTempl
    
End With

nTemplRows = templData.DataBodyRange.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
    
'Check if template table has more rows than build table, if so, add rows to build table
rowsdif = nTemplRows - (tblBuild.Range.Rows.Count - 1)
If rowsdif > 0 Then
    For i = 1 To rowsdif
        tblBuild.ListRows.Add
    Next
End If
        

ClearOrangeCellsRng (tblBuild.Range)

templData.ListColumns("Display Name").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
tblBuild.ListColumns("Description").DataBodyRange(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

templData.ListColumns("Qty").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
tblBuild.ListColumns("Qty per instance").DataBodyRange(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


templData.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
BuildSht.Protect

End Sub


ActiveSheet.Range(r.Address).Replace if the activesheet is not where the range r is located, this will instead run the replace on the activesheet, for the range with the same address as r.   You should use r.Replace ... And ClearOrangeCellsRng (tblBuild.Range) should be ClearOrangeCellsRng tblBuild.Range   Don't use parentheses when calling a sub.

I tested ClearOrangeCellsRng - it doesn't work at all!
So, it's necessary to change it:
Sub ClearOrangeCellsRng(r As Range)
'by range
  Application.FindFormat.Clear
  Application.ReplaceFormat.Clear
  Application.ReplaceFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = -4142
  Application.FindFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 40
  ActiveSheet.Range(r.Address).Replace "", "", searchformat:=True
  Application.FindFormat.Clear
  Application.ReplaceFormat.Clear
End Sub

Now it works as expected and doesn't trespass the range limits.

Copy Specific Columns from One Set of Tables to Another feat Clear Formatting Using the Find Method

After playing around with it, here's what I came up with.
Feel free to rename my somewhat generic variable names (source-destination) as you see fit.
About the immediate issue already covered in rotabor's answer, whenever you see
SomeProcedure (Arg1, Arg2) (focus on the space), it is probably wrong (although it might work). In short:

A sub is called like this SomeSub Arg1, Arg2 (no parentheses): it doesn't return a result, it just does something (You may encounter the also valid Call SomeSub(Arg1, Arg2) (no space) which uses the Call method which is by many considered deprecated (not recommended).).
A function is called like this Result = SomeFunction(Arg1,Arg2) (no space) and should produce a result.



A Call Example
Sub Test()
    Dim BlockNumber As Long
    For BlockNumber = 1 To 3
        BlockTemplate BlockNumber
    Next BlockNumber
End Sub

Main
Sub BlockTemplate(ByVal BlockNumber As Long)
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const SRC_SHEET_NAME As String = "tblTemplates" ' are you sure?
    Const SRC_TABLE_NAME As String = "tblTemplates"
    Const SRC_CRITERIA_COLUMN As Long = 1
    Dim SRC_COLUMN_TITLES() As Variant: SRC_COLUMN_TITLES = VBA _
        .Array("Display Name", "Qty")
    Const DST_GENERIC_NAME As String = "BuildTbl"
    Const DST_BLOCK_LEFT As String = "Build"
    Const DST_BLOCK_RIGHT As String = "Templ"
    Const DST_HIGHLIGHT_COLOR As Long = 10079487 ' Tan, Peach-Orange
    Dim DST_COLUMN_TITLES() As Variant: DST_COLUMN_TITLES = VBA _
        .Array("Description", "Qty per instance")
    
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    ' If it's the workbook containing this code, use 'ThisWorkbook' instead.
    
    ' Source
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET_NAME)
    Dim slo As ListObject: Set slo = sws.ListObjects(SRC_TABLE_NAME)
    Dim sRowsCount As Long: sRowsCount = slo.ListRows.Count
    If sRowsCount = 0 Then Exit Sub ' empty source table
    Dim scrg As Range: Set scrg = slo.DataBodyRange.Columns(SRC_CRITERIA_COLUMN)
    
    ' Destination
    Dim dTableName As String: dTableName = DST_GENERIC_NAME & BlockNumber
    Dim dlo As ListObject: Set dlo = Application.Range(dTableName).ListObject
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dlo.Parent
    Dim BlockName As String: ' name of a single-cell range
    BlockName = DST_BLOCK_LEFT & BlockNumber & DST_BLOCK_RIGHT
    Dim Criterion As Variant: Criterion = dws.Range(BlockName).Value
    
    'Debug.Print slo.Name, dlo.Name, Criterion, scrg.Address
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim sRowMatches As Variant, dRowsCount As Long
    
    ' Retrieve the mathing rows and their count.
    With Application
        sRowMatches = .Match(scrg, Array(Criterion), 0)
        dRowsCount = .Count(sRowMatches)
        If dRowsCount = 0 Then ' no matching rows in source
            If dlo.ListRows.Count > 0 Then
                dlo.DataBodyRange.Delete xlShiftUp
            End If
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    
    ' Define arrays.
    Dim ColumnsCount As Long: ColumnsCount = UBound(DST_COLUMN_TITLES) + 1
    Dim sJag() As Variant: ReDim sJag(1 To ColumnsCount)
    Dim dJag() As Variant: ReDim dJag(1 To ColumnsCount)
    Dim dData() As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To dRowsCount, 1 To 1)
    
    dws.Unprotect
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim dcrg As Range, sRow As Long, dRow As Long, c As Long
    
    ' Copy source range values to arrays of source jagged array
    ' and define arrays of destination jagged array.
    For c = 1 To ColumnsCount
        Set scrg = slo.ListColumns(SRC_COLUMN_TITLES(c - 1)).DataBodyRange
        ' Read source values.
        sJag(c) = scrg.Value
        ' Define corresponding destination array.
        dJag(c) = dData
    Next c
    
    ' Copy matching rows from source to destination arrays.
    If IsArray(sJag(1)) Then ' multiple source rows
        For sRow = 1 To sRowsCount
            If IsNumeric(sRowMatches(sRow, 1)) Then
                dRow = dRow + 1
                For c = 1 To ColumnsCount
                    dJag(c)(dRow, 1) = sJag(c)(sRow, 1)
                Next c
            End If
        Next sRow
    Else ' single source row
        For c = 1 To ColumnsCount
            dJag(c) = sJag(c)
        Next c
    End If
    
    ' Copy matching rows from destination arrays to ranges.
    For c = 1 To ColumnsCount
        Set dcrg = dlo.ListColumns(DST_COLUMN_TITLES(c - 1)).Range _
            .Cells(1).Offset(1).Resize(dRowsCount)
        dcrg.Value = dJag(c)
    Next c
        
    ' Remove excessive (bottom) rows.
    With dlo.DataBodyRange
        Dim dRowDifference As Long:
        dRowDifference = .Rows.Count - dRowsCount
        If dRowDifference > 0 Then
            .Resize(dRowDifference).Offset(dRowsCount).Delete xlShiftUp
        End If
    End With
        
    ' Clear highlights.
    ClearRangeHighlights dlo.DataBodyRange, DST_HIGHLIGHT_COLOR
    
    dws.Protect

End Sub

Help
Sub ClearRangeHighlights( _
        ByRef rg As Range, _
        ByVal HighLightColor As Long)
    With Application
        .FindFormat.Interior.Color = HighLightColor
        .ReplaceFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        rg.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", _
            SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True
        .ReplaceFormat.Clear
        .FindFormat.Clear
    End With
End Sub

